# infinite loop and looking for collision Java

Tags: java, arrays, infinite-loop

I'm trying to look for possible collision within an imaginary box that is 20x20x10 miles and within 10 minutes. All planes have an array of position(x,y,z) and velocity. I'm testing for collision every second and printing out the results, but seems like I have an infinite loop and seems like the results I get from predictX, predictY, predictZ methods are all the same. Any suggestions on how I can go about solving the issue will be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Random;
    public class Plane {
        double[] p=new double[3];
        double[] v=new double[3];
        public Plane(double[] p, double[] v)
        {
            this.p=p;
            this.v=v;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int NUMBER_OF_PLANE = 100;
            Random r=new Random(); //initialize random seed
            int i;
            double[] p={.1,.1,.1}; double[] v={.1,.1,.1};
            Plane[] ac= new Plane [100];
            for (i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_PLANE;i++){
                ac[i] = new Plane (p, v);
                    ac[i].p[0]=20*r.nextDouble();
                    ac[i].p[1]=20*r.nextDouble();
                    ac[i].p[2]=10*r.nextDouble();
                    ac[i].v[0]=100+500*r.nextDouble();
                    if (r.nextBoolean()) v[0] = -v[0];
                    ac[i].v[1]=100+500*r.nextDouble();
                    if (r.nextBoolean()) v[1] = -v[1];
                    ac[i].v[2]=40*r.nextDouble()-20;     
                    ac[i] = new Plane (p,v);
            }
            collision(ac);
        }
        public double predictX(double t) //predicts the position(x) of plane at time t
        {
          double x;
          x = this.p[0] + (t * v[0]);
           return x;
        }
        public double predictY(double t) //predicts the position(y) of plane at time t
        {
          double y;
          y = this.p[1] + (t * v[1]);
          return y;
        }
        public double predictZ(double t) //predicts the height of plane at time t
        {
          double z;
          z = this.p[2] + (t * v[2]);
          return z;
        }

        public static void collision(Plane[] list)
        {
            double time=0;
          while (time<=0.166667){//timer. 0.166667 hours = 10 minutes
            for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
             for (int j=i+1; j<list.length; j++)
             {
                   double iX = list[i].predictX(time);
                   double iY = list[i].predictY(time);
                   double iZ = list[i].predictZ(time);
                   double jX = list[j].predictX(time);
                   double jY = list[j].predictY(time);
                   double jZ = list[j].predictZ(time);
                   if (iX==jX && iY==jY && iZ==jZ){
                       System.out.println("Warning to Aircraft #"+i+": collision in "+time+" seconds with Aircraft #"+j);
                       System.out.println("Position "+iX+", "+iY+" Altitude "+iZ);}
               }
             }
             time+=0.000277778; //1 second
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: One suggestion I can give you is not to use `==` for comparisons of double variables. It's better to test if the difference is smaller than some threshold - for example, `iX-jX < 0.0001` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following code inside a `for` loop in your `main()`:

```
                ac[i] = new Plane (p, v);  // <---------- intial
                 ac[i].p[0]=20*r.nextDouble();
                 ac[i].p[1]=20*r.nextDouble();
                 ac[i].p[2]=10*r.nextDouble();
                 ac[i].v[0]=100+500*r.nextDouble();
                 if (r.nextBoolean()) v[0] = -v[0];
                 ac[i].v[1]=100+500*r.nextDouble();
                 if (r.nextBoolean()) v[1] = -v[1];
                 ac[i].v[2]=40*r.nextDouble()-20;     
                ac[i] = new Plane (p,v);   // <---------- overwrite
```

You initialize `a[i]`, then change some properties and at the end overwrite everything you done.